# Deployed website live. In fiddle everything was fine in Chrome/Phone/Safari. Now in live stuff is messed up

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am completely blown and have absolutely no clue on how to figure this one out.
So far I have been developing a website template in JSFiddle. Now that I had more than enough lines of code I decided to deploy it on one of my old hostings. All I did was save the css, js and html into separate files and then linked the css and js in the index.html along with the jquery 2.0.2 and jquery easing plugin.

**//EDIT** 
Aight. 'body{ margin: 0; padding: 0 }' fixed the navigation bar issue. But it still totally messed up on the phone. Any chance JSFiddle has some "mobile" measures in place?
**end of edit//**

**//EDIT 2** Fullscreen phone screen capture VS chrome's mobile view inspect for samsung galaxy s3.
What could possibly be causing the weird widths and heights in the mobile view?
[image: screns][image: chromescreen] **end of edit 2//**

**//EDIT 3** As I was saying everything is absolutely fine with the JSFiddle result. The below is a screenshot of how the Fiddle looks on phone. There has to be something on JSFiddle making it work which is what I am missing on my site now thats why it messes up only there. The fiddle result is absolutely perfectly responsive, it just craps on the live site[image: jsfiddle phone screen]**end of edit 3//**

**//EDIT 4**Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` into head, made it even worse. :/ **end of edit 4//**

[Here is the JSFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/jason_bright/p3zao4gv/34/embedded/result/) When I open this page on phone, in chrome or safari everything works as intended.

[The live site is here](http://mood2movie.com)

It seems to be the same in safari.

But in chrome the navigation is for some reason 8 pixels away from "left", without it being specified in CSS and I can't solve this by doing `margin-left:-8px` because then I misplace it in Chrome.. Here's an image of that

[image: nav bar issue]

**Finally** when I open the live site on my android phone in Chrome browser the widths are completely messed up.

Am I missing some settings of JSFiddle that I wasn't able to reproduce in my deployment?
If anyone would be so kind to take a look at the live site and the fiddle in the various browser and tell me what could be causing any of these issue I would GREATLY appreciate it.

I'll be looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Looks like it's answered! Nice start for a design. Looks nice!

Comment: It isn't answered yet :( it is completely messed up on phone view.

Comment: Ye, saw that :S I'll take a look at it. Phones tend to mess things up though. Especially when websites have animations and such.

Comment: Have you made sure to include the javascripts that JSFiddle uses? From your last Screenshot you posted it sure looks like some javascript file that is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there a padding is set to body. Remove that padding and you may.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

This will solve the scaling issues you are having on a phone.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: `margin: 0` is what he forgot here.  Also, note that it's best practice _not_ to include a unit of measure if the value is 0.

Comment: Aight. 'body{ margin: 0; padding: 0 }' fixed the navigation bar issue. But it still totally messed up on the phone. Any chance JSFiddle has some "mobile" measures in placE?

Comment: Open in chrome and start the mobile view. You can debug it there.

Comment: ok super weird. When in chrome and I click the mobile button it looks perfectly fine, but on the actual phone it doesn't. Will post screenshots in 2minnutes

Comment: After opening in chrome refresh the page so that chrome sends the correct user agent headers according to the mobile device simulated.

Comment: yeah didnt notice it wasn't set. yeah when I set to galaxy s3 it's just as messed up as on my phone. The problem is I don't know what could possible be causing that. I am using 'vmax' and 'vmin' in some places could they be switched on the phone?

Comment: Use @media queries to create a screen size specific css.

Comment: And what I don't understnad is that when I would go to the JSFiddle result on phone it would be totally fine, but only on the live site it's messed up on phone.so that must have something in place no?

Comment: @AnupamBasak why would I do that when it works perfectly fine on mobile devices with the JSFiddle? It must be something else causing it

Comment: In JSFiddle it is not scaling the page. That's why it looks fine. Try adding this in your head section `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67259/discussion-between-cream-whipped-airplane-and-anupam-basak).